# NSWindows' setFrame:display:animate: doesn't work, setFrame:display: does

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I try to call `setFrame:display:animate:` on my NSWindow and doesn't do anything, but if I call `setFrame:display:` on the same window, it works.
Do I have to do something else to enable resizing with animation?

PS: In C++, if I want to mention a specific class' method I write, for example: `NSWindow::setFrame()` (not only in code but to refer to it in posts) is there such a convention in Objective-C? `[NSWindow setFrame:display:animate:]` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you could just using Core Animation, as in `[[NSWindow animator] setFrame: display:];`

Comment: Great! still don't know why a documented method does nothing, but this one worked fine. thanks